# GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Windows API is giving wrong values even after impersonation is done

Tags: c++, impersonation, msdn, diskspace, nas

I need to find the free space  of a folder in network storage(NAS) where only ***one particular user has full access rights***.

Using **GetDiskFreeSpaceEx** API in C++ it gives me **wrong values (garbage)** when i try to access from a normal domain user without right to that folder . Before the API i impersonate to the user who has full access right and there are no failures during impersonation. I mentioned garbage value is for the reason that when i try to access different folder in different drive of same storage i get the same values.

If i change the access rights of that folder to "Everyone" and use API without Impersonation it returns proper values.

For impersonation, logon i have tried with both **LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE** and **LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK**.

Am i missing something here? Some sort of additional permission rights to be given?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant right according to the MSDN documentation of `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` is "The calling application must have **FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY** access rights for this directory.".

What slightly worries me is the first part, "the calling application ...". Impersonation works on threads, but MSDN doesn't say "The calling thread must ...".

ANother concern would how you name the NAS drive. If you use a drive letter mapping, that drive letter mapping may not be available while impersonating another user.